# Powershell remote access denied on workgroup

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, command-line-interface, remote-access

I've configured a domenstic network with PCs running windows 10 and I'm trying to set up remote access via powershell between these hosts.
I've enabled remote access on all the hosts, authorizing all the hosts to control AND be controlled by all the hosts in the network, I've tested the connection between two PCs and it seems to be working cause the following returns no error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> test-WSman 192.168.1.132
 wsmid           : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/identity/1/wsmanidentity.xsd 
 ProtocolVersion : http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd 
 ProductVendor   : Microsoft Corporation                        
 ProductVersion  : OS: 0.0.0 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
```

but, when I try to establish a full session between the two hosts with the following command, I get error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.132 -Credential User1            

Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server 192.168.1.132 failed        
with the following error message : Access is denied.                               
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.                                                       
At line:1 char:1                                                             
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.132 -Credential User1                        
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument:(192.168.1.132:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

After issuing this command, of course, pops-up the dialog box, asking for password. 
Maybe, the error could be in the credential I'm issuing...where do I get valid and acceptable credentials(user & password) in Windows, for connecting to a remote machine in my home network?

Do I need to create new ones, with get-credential cmdlet, or maybe credentials are tied to the local account on the machine I'm connecting from, or perhaps on the machine I'm connecting to?
I'm totally inexpert in this field so I don't know how to solve it

P.S. I'm in a simply windows workgroup(with no home-group setted), not in a domain 
so the machines are in peer-to-peer configuration

Comment: Credentials then have to be in the form of `computername\username` (or only username, if it is the same on all machines) if the PCs are not connected to a domain or anything. Don't forget to set firewall etc.. But I'll have to voteclose this because it's about a home network. You can ask the question again on [https://superuser.com/](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Ok but which credentials are supposed to be used? username and password tied to windows account I'm running on the PC(that would be an e-mail username plus password)? Or I need to create a new ones using the get-credential cmdlet or, again, it's a single-use credentials created at the moment, simply issuing an arbitrary username+password?...Anyway I've tried all these scenarios but the error is always the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the devices you are using to remote from to the trusted host list on the device you are trying to manage?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx

Comment: Yes, and I did the same on the device I'm connecting from, adding the remote one to its trusted host list

Comment: I assume you check and confirm that WINRM is configured correctly and behaving itself?